# How to change the imagebutton over another activity?

Tags: java, android

I have onClick method and when you click on the onclick change the ImageButton in MainActivitiy.class

This is my onClick:

```
    public void onClick8 (View view) {
        //Here should go command to change ImageButton in MainActivity.class
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(zem13.this, R.raw.song);
        mediaPlayer.start();

  }
```

If you can please show the code as it is to be set in MainActivity.class and other activity.

Answer (score 0):

use string references and set the string from another activity and when you came back to your activity you can change the image with an `if`

Comment: it depends on your code; can you use preferences ? you can check you preferences changes in onResume function

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly
use can use `myIntent.putExtra("TAG",changes)` method in your activity and `changes=getIntent.getExtra("TAG")` in MainActivity.
the other way is using SharedPreferences
using BroadcastReceiver is another solution